# How to transform a Java POJO to CSV using Smooks?

Tags: smooks

The title says it all. I couldn't find an example of a Smooks config mapping a POJO to a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

OOTB, Smooks doesn't have a writer that is specific to CSV. Use Smooks's template cartridge (i.e., Freemarker or StringTemplate) or develop a visitor to read from the SAX stream and generate CSV.